# Installing Jelly Bean on Ice Cream Sandwich tablet

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, updates

I just bought this China-made tablet, [Ainol Novo Flame](http://www.ainolindia.com/ainol-novo-7-flame.html), and it has Ice Cream Sandwich installed on it.

Is there anyway to install Jelly Bean? I Googled some and couldn't find a good source. Do you know any? thanks

I hope this is the right place to ask. I'm new to android overall.

Comment: I'd recommend checking [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)

Comment: Well I also happen to have a flame and I upgraded it to 4.2 Jellybean by following this [LINK](http://forums.ainolstore.com/topic/1285-aokp-42-for-elf-ii-aurora-ii-crystal-flame-fire-hero-updated-24022013/) It is based on AOKP. Works well on the flame, and brings the much needed multi-user profile for family use. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the latest Official Ainol Novo 7 Fire JellyBean [firmware](http://bbs.ainol.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=53234&extra=page=1) (using the latest Android version 4.2.2):

Google Translation maybe required.

Comment: I read somewhere Flame and fire are identically have same hardware but a bit different software. do you think it could cause a problem?

Comment: @ePezhman To be on the safe side I would ask that at http://www.slatedroid.com/, a website very much into custom ROMs for alternative chinese tablets

Comment: @ePezhman I know that they give different names to the same tablet in different markets, should be identical, but just in case, always better to be safe.

Comment: Trust me it is the SAME. I have one and I know it. I also use the firmware interchangeably with no noticeable downsides. It is probably just a mistranslation from the distributors part, because you know its chinese.

Comment: @ePezhman Your welcome, hope that you enjoy it :)